# How to strip last bits from ip address

Tags: python, ip-address

How do I zero out the last *n* digits of an IP address in Python? I'd prefer solutions using the standard library, most likely [ipaddress](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ipaddress).

Some `strip_addr` testcases would look like:

```
assert strip_addr(u'1.2.3.4', 24) == u'1.2.3.0'
assert strip_addr(u'2001:1234:f678::9', 33) == u'2001:1234:8000::'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [interface network objects](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/ipaddress.html#inspecting-address-network-interface-objects)?

```
import ipaddress

def strip_addr(ip, bits):
    nwif = ipaddress.ip_interface(u'%s/%s' % (ip, bits))
    return str(nwif.network.network_address)

assert strip_addr(u'1.2.3.4', 24) == u'1.2.3.0'
assert strip_addr(u'2001:1234:f678::9', 33) == u'2001:1234:8000::'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, interface network objects are the solution here. I took the liberty of somewhat simplifying your answer. Feel free to revert if you don't agree.

Comment: Nice catch with the `network_address` attribute, eliminating the need to mess with string splitting! (And, I suppose having the `assert` statements in their own function for compatibility with [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) tests was a bit much for this small example. =)